# Change the path of index.html in a react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a React App, and by default, the index.html goes to the public folder. So when I run the command npm start, the index.html needs to be at the public folder otherwise I'll get the following error:

```
...
react-scripts start

Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
...
```

So my question is if there is any way where I can change the index.html to the root path.

I mean the following:

**From here (which is the default)**

```
my-app/
  README.md
  node_modules/
  package.json
  public/
    index.html
    favicon.ico
  src/
    App.css
    App.js
    App.test.js
    index.css
    index.js
    logo.svg
```

**To here:**

```
my-app/
  README.md
  node_modules/
  package.json
  public/
    favicon.ico
  src/
    App.css
    App.js
    App.test.js
    index.css
    index.js
    logo.svg
index.html
```

I need to do this as I have a javascript file called record.js that I would like to include in my index.html, but I also want it to be used by a component called Speech.js so the only way I see that I can do it is that way.

Comment: Why don't you use record.js in your /src directories? I don't think it is a good practice to add non-react .js files into your index.html

Comment: So do you think I need to change the javascript file into a component?

Comment: that depends on the context of your record.js, can you describe what it does?

Comment: The recorder.js is the following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501412/how-to-import-a-javascript-from-src-folder-in-a-react-component?noredirect=1#comment91953594_52501412

Answer (score 0):

One easy way could be by creating a new app

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app App
```

You’ll have a folder structure that looks like this:

```
App/
  README.md
  **index.html**
  favicon.ico
  node_modules/
  package.json
  src/
    App.css
    App.js
    index.css
    index.js
    logo.svg
```

As you can see your index.html is in the root path so you just need to add your files to it.

Comment: Could not create a project called "App" because of npm naming restrictions:
  *  name can no longer contain capital letters