# How to import a javascript from src folder in a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following architecture:

```
my-app/
  README.md
  node_modules/
  package.json
  public/
    favicon.ico
    index.html
  src/
    App.css
    App.js
    App.test.js
    index.css
    index.js
    logo.svg
    recorder.js
    componentsFolder
         Speech.css
         Speech.js
```

I want to import be able to import the recorder.js javascript file to the Speech.js but I've not managed to do it but just using import or require as I always get the following error:

I get the following error:

```
./src/components/Speech.js
Module not found: You attempted to import /recorder which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
```

So I believe there is another way that could actually work.

I attach the two files:

**Speech.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import './Speech.css';
// import './Speech.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import Recorder from '../recorder'


export default class Speech extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      btn: true,
      btnStop: false,
      loader: false,
      result: false,
      resultError: false,
      textResult: '',
      apiKey: 'd9cf10ae33dfbbd03e58d9adfd0a75ef88159d63', // api key
      selected: 'en-US',
      items: [
        {
          text: 'English (United States)',
          value: 'en-US'
        }
      ],
      data: {
        audio: {
          content: null
        },
        config: {
          encoding: 'LINEAR16',
          sampleRateHertz: 44100,
          languageCode: null
        }
      }
    };
  }

  startUserMedia(stream) {
    const input = window.audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    // Media stream created

    // const { Recorder: myRecorder } = require('/recorder');
    // console.log(myRecorder);

    // require('/recorder');
    this.recorder = new Recorder(input);
    // Recorder initialised
  }

  startRecording() {
    // Start Recording
    this.recorder && this.recorder.record();
    this.state.result = false;
    this.state.btn = false;
    this.state.btnStop = true;
    setTimeout(this.stopRecording, 58000);
  }

  stopRecording() {
    // Stopped Recording
    this.recorder && this.recorder.stop();
    this.state.btnStop = false;
    this.state.loader = true;
    // create WAV download link using audio data blob
    this.processRecording();
    this.recorder.clear();
  }

  processRecording() {
    const vm = this;

    this.recorder &&
      this.recorder.exportWAV(blob => {
        const reader = new window.FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        reader.onloadend = () => {
          const baseData = reader.result;
          const base64Data = baseData.replace('data:audio/wav;base64,', '');
          vm.data.audio.content = base64Data;
          vm.data.config.languageCode = vm.state.selected;
          axios
            .post(
              `https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=${vm.state.apiKey}`,
              vm.data
            )
            .then(response => {
              const result = response.data.results[0].alternatives[0];
              vm.state.textResult = result.transcript;
              vm.state.btn = true;
              vm.state.loader = false;
              vm.state.result = true;
            })
            .catch(error => {
              vm.state.loader = false;
              vm.state.resultError = true;
              console.log(`ERROR:${error}`);
            });
        };
      });
  }

  redirectError() {
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/';
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    try {
      window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
      navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
      window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

      window.audio_context = new AudioContext();
      console.log('Audio context set up.');
      console.log(
        `navigator.getUserMedia ${navigator.getUserMedia ? 'available.' : 'not present!'}`
      );
    } catch (e) {
      alert('No web audio support in this browser!');
    }
    const that = this;
    navigator.getUserMedia(
      {
        audio: true
      },
      stream => {
        that.state.startUserMedia(stream);
      },
      e => {
        console.log(`No live audio input: ${e}`);
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <layout row wrap>
          <select show="btn" items={this.state.items} model="selected" label="Select a language" />
          <button onClick={this.startRecording} block round color="primary" dark>
            <icon left>mic</icon>
            Recording
          </button>
          <button onClick={this.stopRecording} block round color="error" dark>
            <icon left>stop</icon>
            Stop
          </button>
          <div>
            <progress-circle indeterminate size="100" width="3" class="orange--text" />
          </div>
          <transition name="slide">
            <div>
              <layout row wrap>
                  <card className="darken-2 orange--text">
                    <h4 className="text-xs-center">{this.state.textResult}</h4>
                  </card>
              </layout>
            </div>
          </transition>
          <transition name="slide">
            <div v-show="resultError" className="text-xs-center">
              <layout row wrap>
                <col />
                <col>
                  <card className="red darken-3 white--text">
                    <card-title primary-title>
                      <div className="headline">An Unexpected Error Occurred</div>
                    </card-title>
                    <card-actions>
                      <button onClick={this.redirectError} flat dark>
                        Try Again
                      </button>
                    </card-actions>
                  </card>
                </col>
                <col />
              </layout>
            </div>
          </transition>
      </layout>
    );
  }
}
```

---

**recorder.js**

```
(function (f) {
  if (typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = f()
  } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define([], f)
  } else {
    var g
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      g = window
    } else if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
      g = global
    } else if (typeof self !== 'undefined') {
      g = self
    } else {
      g = this
    }
    g.Recorder = f()
  }
})(function () {
  var define, module, exports
  return (function e (t, n, r) {
    function s (o, u) {
      if (!n[o]) {
        if (!t[o]) {
          var a = typeof require === 'function' && require
          if (!u && a) return a(o, !0)
          if (i) return i(o, !0)
          var f = new Error("Cannot find module '" + o + "'")
          throw f.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', f
        }
        var l = n[o] = {
          exports: {}
        }
        t[o][0].call(l.exports, function (e) {
          var n = t[o][1][e]
          return s(n || e)
        }, l, l.exports, e, t, n, r)
      }
      return n[o].exports
    }
    var i = typeof require === 'function' && require
    for (var o = 0; o < r.length; o++) s(r[o])
    return s
  })({
    1: [function (require, module, exports) {
      'use strict'

      module.exports = require('./recorder').Recorder
    }, {
      './recorder': 2
    }],
    2: [function (require, module, exports) {
      'use strict'

      var _createClass = (function () {
        function defineProperties (target, props) {
          for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
            var descriptor = props[i]
            descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false
            descriptor.configurable = true
            if ('value' in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true
            Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor)
          }
        }
        return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
          if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps)
          if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps)
          return Constructor
        }
      })()

      Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {
        value: true
      })
      exports.Recorder = undefined

      var _inlineWorker = require('inline-worker')

      var _inlineWorker2 = _interopRequireDefault(_inlineWorker)

      function _interopRequireDefault (obj) {
        return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : {
          default: obj
        }
      }

      function _classCallCheck (instance, Constructor) {
        if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
          throw new TypeError('Cannot call a class as a function')
        }
      }

      var Recorder = exports.Recorder = (function () {
        function Recorder (source, cfg) {
          var _this = this

          _classCallCheck(this, Recorder)

          this.config = {
            bufferLen: 4096,
            numChannels: 1,
            mimeType: 'audio/wav'
          }
          this.recording = false
          this.callbacks = {
            getBuffer: [],
            exportWAV: []
          }

          Object.assign(this.config, cfg)
          this.context = source.context
          this.node = (this.context.createScriptProcessor || this.context.createJavaScriptNode).call(this.context, this.config.bufferLen, this.config.numChannels, this.config.numChannels)

          this.node.onaudioprocess = function (e) {
            if (!_this.recording) return

            var buffer = []
            for (var channel = 0; channel < _this.config.numChannels; channel++) {
              buffer.push(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(channel))
            }
            _this.worker.postMessage({
              command: 'record',
              buffer: buffer
            })
          }

          source.connect(this.node)
          this.node.connect(this.context.destination) // this should not be necessary

          var self = {}
          this.worker = new _inlineWorker2.default(function () {
            var recLength = 0

            var recBuffers = []

            var sampleRate = undefined

            var numChannels = undefined

            self.onmessage = function (e) {
              switch (e.data.command) {
                case 'init':
                  init(e.data.config)
                  break
                case 'record':
                  record(e.data.buffer)
                  break
                case 'exportWAV':
                  exportWAV(e.data.type)
                  break
                case 'getBuffer':
                  getBuffer()
                  break
                case 'clear':
                  clear()
                  break
              }
            }

            function init (config) {
              sampleRate = config.sampleRate
              numChannels = config.numChannels
              initBuffers()
            }

            function record (inputBuffer) {
              for (var channel = 0; channel < numChannels; channel++) {
                recBuffers[channel].push(inputBuffer[channel])
              }
              recLength += inputBuffer[0].length
            }

            function exportWAV (type) {
              var buffers = []
              for (var channel = 0; channel < numChannels; channel++) {
                buffers.push(mergeBuffers(recBuffers[channel], recLength))
              }
              var interleaved = undefined
              if (numChannels === 2) {
                interleaved = interleave(buffers[0], buffers[1])
              } else {
                interleaved = buffers[0]
              }
              var dataview = encodeWAV(interleaved)
              var audioBlob = new Blob([dataview], {
                type: type
              })

              self.postMessage({
                command: 'exportWAV',
                data: audioBlob
              })
            }

            function getBuffer () {
              var buffers = []
              for (var channel = 0; channel < numChannels; channel++) {
                buffers.push(mergeBuffers(recBuffers[channel], recLength))
              }
              self.postMessage({
                command: 'getBuffer',
                data: buffers
              })
            }

            function clear () {
              recLength = 0
              recBuffers = []
              initBuffers()
            }

            function initBuffers () {
              for (var channel = 0; channel < numChannels; channel++) {
                recBuffers[channel] = []
              }
            }

            function mergeBuffers (recBuffers, recLength) {
              var result = new Float32Array(recLength)
              var offset = 0
              for (var i = 0; i < recBuffers.length; i++) {
                result.set(recBuffers[i], offset)
                offset += recBuffers[i].length
              }
              return result
            }

            function interleave (inputL, inputR) {
              var length = inputL.length + inputR.length
              var result = new Float32Array(length)

              var index = 0

              var inputIndex = 0

              while (index < length) {
                result[index++] = inputL[inputIndex]
                result[index++] = inputR[inputIndex]
                inputIndex++
              }
              return result
            }

            function floatTo16BitPCM (output, offset, input) {
              for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++, offset += 2) {
                var s = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, input[i]))
                output.setInt16(offset, s < 0 ? s * 0x8000 : s * 0x7FFF, true)
              }
            }

            function writeString (view, offset, string) {
              for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
                view.setUint8(offset + i, string.charCodeAt(i))
              }
            }

            function encodeWAV (samples) {
              var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + samples.length * 2)
              var view = new DataView(buffer)

              /* RIFF identifier */
              writeString(view, 0, 'RIFF')
              /* RIFF chunk length */
              view.setUint32(4, 36 + samples.length * 2, true)
              /* RIFF type */
              writeString(view, 8, 'WAVE')
              /* format chunk identifier */
              writeString(view, 12, 'fmt ')
              /* format chunk length */
              view.setUint32(16, 16, true)
              /* sample format (raw) */
              view.setUint16(20, 1, true)
              /* channel count */
              view.setUint16(22, numChannels, true)
              /* sample rate */
              view.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true)
              /* byte rate (sample rate * block align) */
              view.setUint32(28, sampleRate * 4, true)
              /* block align (channel count * bytes per sample) */
              view.setUint16(32, numChannels * 2, true)
              /* bits per sample */
              view.setUint16(34, 16, true)
              /* data chunk identifier */
              writeString(view, 36, 'data')
              /* data chunk length */
              view.setUint32(40, samples.length * 2, true)

              floatTo16BitPCM(view, 44, samples)

              return view
            }
          }, self)

          this.worker.postMessage({
            command: 'init',
            config: {
              sampleRate: this.context.sampleRate,
              numChannels: this.config.numChannels
            }
          })

          this.worker.onmessage = function (e) {
            var cb = _this.callbacks[e.data.command].pop()
            if (typeof cb === 'function') {
              cb(e.data.data)
            }
          }
        }

        _createClass(Recorder, [{
          key: 'record',
          value: function record () {
            this.recording = true
          }
        }, {
          key: 'stop',
          value: function stop () {
            this.recording = false
          }
        }, {
          key: 'clear',
          value: function clear () {
            this.worker.postMessage({
              command: 'clear'
            })
          }
        }, {
          key: 'getBuffer',
          value: function getBuffer (cb) {
            cb = cb || this.config.callback
            if (!cb) throw new Error('Callback not set')

            this.callbacks.getBuffer.push(cb)

            this.worker.postMessage({
              command: 'getBuffer'
            })
          }
        }, {
          key: 'exportWAV',
          value: function exportWAV (cb, mimeType) {
            mimeType = mimeType || this.config.mimeType
            cb = cb || this.config.callback
            if (!cb) throw new Error('Callback not set')

            this.callbacks.exportWAV.push(cb)

            this.worker.postMessage({
              command: 'exportWAV',
              type: mimeType
            })
          }
        }], [{
          key: 'forceDownload',
          value: function forceDownload (blob, filename) {
            var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob)
            var link = window.document.createElement('a')
            link.href = url
            link.download = filename || 'output.wav'
            var click = document.createEvent('Event')
            click.initEvent('click', true, true)
            link.dispatchEvent(click)
          }
        }])

        return Recorder
      })()

      exports.default = Recorder
    }, {
      'inline-worker': 3
    }],
    3: [function (require, module, exports) {
      'use strict'

      module.exports = require('./inline-worker')
    }, {
      './inline-worker': 4
    }],
    4: [function (require, module, exports) {
      (function (global) {
        'use strict'

        var _createClass = (function () {
          function defineProperties (target, props) {
            for (var key in props) {
              var prop = props[key]
              prop.configurable = true
              if (prop.value) prop.writable = true
            }
            Object.defineProperties(target, props)
          }
          return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
            if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps)
            if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps)
            return Constructor
          }
        })()

        var _classCallCheck = function (instance, Constructor) {
          if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
            throw new TypeError('Cannot call a class as a function')
          }
        }

        var WORKER_ENABLED = !!(global === global.window && global.URL && global.Blob && global.Worker)

        var InlineWorker = (function () {
          function InlineWorker (func, self) {
            var _this = this

            _classCallCheck(this, InlineWorker)

            if (WORKER_ENABLED) {
              var functionBody = func.toString().trim().match(/^function\s*\w*\s*\([\w\s,]*\)\s*{([\w\W]*?)}$/)[1]
              var url = global.URL.createObjectURL(new global.Blob([functionBody], {
                type: 'text/javascript'
              }))

              return new global.Worker(url)
            }

            this.self = self
            this.self.postMessage = function (data) {
              setTimeout(function () {
                _this.onmessage({
                  data: data
                })
              }, 0)
            }

            setTimeout(function () {
              func.call(self)
            }, 0)
          }

          _createClass(InlineWorker, {
            postMessage: {
              value: function postMessage (data) {
                var _this = this

                setTimeout(function () {
                  _this.self.onmessage({
                    data: data
                  })
                }, 0)
              }
            }
          })

          return InlineWorker
        })()

        module.exports = InlineWorker
      }).call(this, typeof global !== 'undefined' ? global : typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : {})
    }, {}]
  }, {}, [1])(1)
})
```

Comment: So, from what file do you try to import? Maybe the path is wrong.

Comment: I'm trying to recorder.js into the component Speech.js

Comment: Thought I would share my solution to "Import ReactJS component from another file?": https://stackoverflow.com/a/45284831/2430549  I think this might help.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger I think it's not the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You're pointing to a file that doesn't exist.  From `my-app/src/componentsFolder/Speech.js` you need to import from `../recorder`

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult when we can see the error, but not the code that caused it. I see a few issues, and I hope at least one of them is helpful.

First, in the tree you provided, App.css is in the middle of the tree, but includes no indentation. I'll assume that is incorrect and should be in the /src folder. I don't know if there are other errors also in the structure.

In addition, your error says it's looking for /recorder. This would also appear incorrect. Are you looking for '/recorder' or './recorder'? The latter would be the preferred import. Also, are you using export, export default, or modules.export for the recorder.js?

Comment: I would like to import Recorder from recorder.js. I'll attach the files in the description of my question so you can have a better understanding.